# Rails is checking the new user form when hitting the projects#index route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error regarding my new user form when I hit my project#index route: 
[image]

As you can see from the picture, a user is actually currently logged in. I am not sure why that form is being called. Here is some additional info starting with my projects controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @projects = Project.all
    end

    def new
        @project = Project.new
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end

    def show
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @project = Project.create(project_params)
        if @project.save
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                redirect_to({:controller => 'application', :action => 'home'}, :notice => 'Oh no! Something went wrong!.')
            end

        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end

    def edit
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])    
    end

    def update
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        @project = Project.update(project_params)
        redirect_to project_path
    end

    def destroy
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
        @project.destroy
        redirect_to root_path

        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end

        private
        def project_params
            params.require(:project).permit(:name, :type, :description, :money_needed, :money_raised, :end_date, :user_id)
        end
```

end

here are my routes if it helps:
[image]

Here is my index.html.erb for my projects:

```
<div id ="project">
    <h2><%= project.name %></h2>
    <div><%= project.url %></div> <!-- this should be a thumbnail or sized in some way -->
    <p><%= project.description %></p>
    <p><%= project.money_needed %></p> <!-- this should be a progress bar -->
</div>
```

Any ideas as to how to fix this, and clarification on what is happening is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you rendering _new.html.erb in your index view?

Comment: no, i will update my question with that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your index method you don't actually define @user

```
def index
    @projects = Project.all
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end
```

#### Edit

You could also simply use:

```
@user = current_user
```

seems a bit more elegant :)

Comment: Awesome!!!! that worked!! Can you explain a little bit why I need to define a user in order for someone to see a list of all the projects? I would like someone who is not logged in to be able to view projects. Also should I be adding this line to all my project functions or something? I will mark this as the answer as soon as SO allows ;)

Comment: To be honest, I think, either in your application layout or somewhere else you render the user/new partial ... which forces you to have user defined everywhere in your app. Once you identify where/when this partial is called, you could either remove the render partial and the problem will disappear or if you absolutely need it leave it be and declare user in your methods.

Comment: Yes! in my nav, the user login and signup are partials that are being being called like this in the application.html.erb: `<%= render 'users/log_in_form'%></div>`   so that explanation makes sense and clears up a LOT for me!!! Thank you so much for your help, and for clearing that up, as I had no idea it would have this effect :)

Comment: Not a problem @HolyMoly ! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render `index` page for a signed_in user, you need to instantiate the `@user` in the `index` action:

```
 def index 
    @projects = Project.all
    @user = current_user
 end
```

Comment: I will see what happens when I take it out, as I recall, I was getting errors when I didn't have it - but I have had so many problems with this particular project (which I never had with other rails apps) all the errors are a blur at this point, lol. But I am learning a lot from all these new problems!

Answer (score 0):

@user is nil , you have to define it in the controller.

```
 def index 
      @projects = Project.all
      @user = current_user
 end
```

Depending what you're trying to do, you can also make the form like this:

```
 <%= form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
```

And omit all the definitions of the user in the controller.